# Error entity framework .net 6.0 C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

estoy implementando entity framework en un proyecto .net 6.0 de escritorio. Al ejecutar la verificacion de migraciones me arroja el siguiente error:

> Cannot use table 'comprobantes' for entity type
> 'Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente' since it is being used for entity type
> 'Comprobantes' and potentially other entity types, but there is no
> linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente'
> on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on
> another entity type mapped to 'comprobantes'.

Alguno tiene idea por que es esto?

A continuacion dejo mi codigo:

Mi contexto:

```
    using EntityFramework.Configuracion;

namespace EntityFramework.Data;

public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente>? Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comprobantes>? Comprobantes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comprobantes_Tipo>? Comprobantes_Tipo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"server=localhost;database=db_storesys_test;user=root;port=3306;password=15648836";
       optionsBuilder.UseMySql
            (ConnectionString,
            ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString));
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ComprobanteTipoConfiguracion());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ComprobanteConfiguracion());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UsuarioCuentaCorrienteConfiguracion());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string Mensaje = ex.Message;
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

Mis configuracion (Usuario cuenta corriente)

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace EntityFramework.Configuracion;
public class UsuarioCuentaCorrienteConfiguracion : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("comprobantes");
        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.clienteCuentaCorrienteId).HasName("clienteCuentaCorrienteId");
        modelBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Comprobante).WithOne(p => p!.usuarioCuentaCorriente);
    }
}
```

Mi configuracion (Comprobante):

```
using EntityFramework.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace EntityFramework.Configuracion; 
public class ComprobanteConfiguracion : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Comprobantes>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comprobantes> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("comprobantes");
        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.comprobanteId);
        modelBuilder.Property(e => e.comprobanteDescripcion).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Property(e => e.fechaEfectuado).IsRequired().HasColumnName("fechaEfectuado");
        modelBuilder.HasOne(e => e.comprobanteTipo).WithOne(p => p!.Comprobante);
        modelBuilder.HasOne(e => e.usuarioCuentaCorriente).WithOne(p => p!.Comprobante);
    }
}
```

Mi configuracino (Comprobante tipo)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace EntityFramework.Configuracion;

public class ComprobanteTipoConfiguracion : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Comprobantes_Tipo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comprobantes_Tipo> modelBuilder)
    {
        //ESTRUCTURA
        modelBuilder.ToTable("comprobantes_tipo");
        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.comprobanteTipoId);
        modelBuilder.Property(e => e.descripcion).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Comprobante).WithOne(p => p!.comprobanteTipo);

        //DATOS FIJOS
        modelBuilder.HasData(
            new Comprobantes_Tipo
            {
                comprobanteTipoId = 1,
                descripcion = "PEDIDO"
            },
            new Comprobantes_Tipo
            {
                comprobanteTipoId = 2,
                descripcion = "COMPROBANTE DE DEUDA"
            },
            new Comprobantes_Tipo
            {
                comprobanteTipoId = 3,
                descripcion = "FACTURA A"
            },
            new Comprobantes_Tipo
            {
                comprobanteTipoId = 4,
                descripcion = "FACTURA B"
            },
            new Comprobantes_Tipo
            {
                comprobanteTipoId = 5,
                descripcion = "PRUEBA"
            },
            new Comprobantes_Tipo
            {
                comprobanteTipoId = 6,
                descripcion = "PRUEBA2"
            });
    }
}
```

Anotacion:
EL ERROR ME LO TIRA EN TEORIA EN LA TABLA USUARIOS CUENTA CORRIENTE CUANDO QUIERO ESTABLECER LA RELACION CON LA TABLA COMPROBANTES, SEGUN ESTOY LEYENDO EN EL MENSAJE DE ERROR

Comment: Veo que le estás diciendo a EF que existe una relación entre las tablas, pero no especificas la llave foránea. Por qué? No veo ningún `.HasForeignKey()`, por qué? Ya revisaste la documentación oficial de EF acerca de [Relaciones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)?

Comment: @Arriel Espectacular, esto me sirvio gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La entidad `Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente` deberia crear la tabla `clienteCuentaCorriente`. Ahora intenta crear la tabla `comprobantes` y esa tabla ya existe.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class UsuarioCuentaCorrienteConfiguracion : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Usuarios_Cuenta_Corriente> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("clienteCuentaCorriente");
        modelBuilder.HasKey(e => e.clienteCuentaCorrienteId).HasName("clienteCuentaCorrienteId");
        modelBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Comprobante).WithOne(p => p!.usuarioCuentaCorriente);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @gcores lo pude resolver con el comentario que me enviaron arriba, gracias!

Comment: @AlejoMoya si el comentario de la pregunta dio con la respuesta, puedes colocar la respuesta en la parte inferior y luego marcarla como aceptada, de este modo ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx Ya lo marque es el comentario de la anterior, creo que lo marque bien no ? Cualquier cosa corregime porfa gracias!

Comment: Un placer colaborar hermano, veamos, al costado de las respuestas hay un "check" que solo el que hizo la pregunta puede ver y presionar. Como esta pregunta donde estamos comentando no ha dado con la solución de tu escenario, no se marca como aceptada. Lo que has realizado es una votación al comentario. Entonces, dadas las circunstancias del caso, te sugiero incluir en la caja de texto de abajo que dice "Tu Respuesta" y agregar lo que realizaste para dar con la solución, podrías incluir un mensaje de agradecimiento al usuario del comentario. Saludos.